# Unable to locate package s-nail ubuntu 16

Tags: server

i am trying to install s-nail and i am getting this error..

tried it to google it but there is no luck

the packages are already updated "sudo apt-get update"
i am using Ubuntu 16,

```
sudo apt-get install s-nail
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree   
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package s-nail
```

please help thank you

Comment: Did you enable the universe repository?

Answer (score 0):

Well this error could be possibly of two things ,

1. You might not have the info about s-nail package in your ubuntu package cache.
2. You won't be having universe repo of xenial.

I recommend you to follow the steps below.

```
echo "deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install s-nail
```

Comment: `$ sudo echo "deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
bash: /etc/apt/sources.list: Permission denied`

Comment: become privileged user first to avoid denial of permission. So run this command  sudo -i  then run the former commands.